# Ruby Lazy Enumerable flat_map is not very lazy

Tags: ruby, lazy-evaluation, enumerable

Edit: Since I wrote the question with a wrong example and didn't describe my issues, I'll do it again!

It seems to me that #flat_map, even though part of the Enumerator::Lazy class, is not very enumerable itself.

This example correctly works:

```
(1..Float::INFINITY).flat_map { |s| [s,s] }.take(4).to_a
```

The lazy implementation will also work:

```
(1..Float::INFINITY).flat_map { |s| [s,s] }.take(4).to_a
```

This will only take into account that the array generated within the block are finite. But they will also be fully evaluated before the take(4) call takes place. Which is not very lazyable.

Hence, this will fail:

```
(1..Float::INFINITY).lazy.flat_map { |i| (i..Float::INFINITY).map(&:to_i) }.take(4).force
```

Because the "infinity range to array" will be fully evaluated before the lazy call takes place. I would expect it to be "lazy by default", though. I mean, I do understand where the conundrum lies, but I'd expect it to happen this way: flat_map evaluates each instance lazy, knows that the result will be an array (or enumerable, at least), and will apply the lazy mechanism on it. hence, (i..Float::INFINITY).map(&:to_i) would be lazified (which doesn't seem very compatible, since the map(&:to_i) call will "force" it to be calculated).

Comment: This could be a bug in the implementation.

Comment: @tadman: the OP is `flat_map`ping a `Range`, not an `Enumerator::Lazy`. There simply is no laziness here, nor would you expect there to be.

Comment: Jesus, only noticed now the missing #lazy call... I'll have to go back to my failing example to see what was my initial problem again.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a problem when wrapping lazy collections. I'll try to rewrite

Comment: Aren't first two code lines exactly the same? Why you say one is lazy and other is not

Answer (score 7):

You are not actually using a lazy enumerator. To convert a normal enumerator to a lazy one, use the `Enumerable#lazy` method. To get the results back I'd recommend using the method `Enumerable::Lazy#force` instead of `to_a` because I think it shows the intention more clearly.

```
(1..Float::INFINITY).lazy.flat_map { |s| [s,s] }.take(4).force
#=> [1, 1, 2, 2]
```